# How to access remote machine terminal that is connected via USB serial?

Tags: usb, serial, remote

I have a remote machine running Ubuntu that has an on-board USB serial converter. I can easily access remote's terminal by connecting via USB to Windows and running PuTTY. However, is it possible to get to remote's terminal this way using the RPi 4 terminal? Essentially, I'd like to replace the Windows machine and PuTTY with the RPi 4.

When I connect remote's console port to RPi 4, it is immediately recognized and attached to `/dev/ttyUSB0`

```
$ dmesg
$ ...
$ usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
$ usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6015, bcdDevice=10.00
$ usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
$ usb 1-1.1: Product: FT231X USB UART
$ usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: FTDI
$ usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: D200BOAV
$ ftdi_sio 1-1.1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
$ usb 1-1.1: Detected FT-X
$ usb 1-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

From the RPi 4 terminal, how can I access remote's terminal?

Comment: your question does not really belong here ... it should be asked at a linux site https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Use a terminal program like `minicom` or `seyon` or others. Even PuTTY is available. See also https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/5-linux-unix-commands-for-connecting-to-the-serial-console/ or https://developer.toradex.com/linux-bsp/how-to/hardware-related/serial-terminal-emulator/

Answer (score -1):

Run a SSH server on the Ubuntu machine.

Then use SSH on the Pi to open a terminal  on the  Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I am specifically trying to connect via USB serial port. Is SSH capable of this?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  What's stopping you from using minicom or screen?

Comment: I would like to automate filesharing between multiple machines. It is simple with SSH and using an ethernet connection between the two. I use crontab to periodically rsync between the machines. However, since the RPi only has one ethernet port and multiple USB ports, I thought it may be possible to do this through USB serial.

Comment: minicom and screen are Linux commands which do pretty much the same as putty.   Perhaps you need to clarify your  question.

Comment: Can minicom or screen be used without their window interface? For example, I'd like to echo "Hello" on a remote machine. Can this be done without opening minicom? Similar to `$ ssh root@remote echo Hello`

Comment: @earl see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96718/how-do-i-use-a-serial-port-on-linux-like-a-pipe-or-netcat

Comment: Why are you using a serial link, why not just network the 2 devices together using WiFi or Ethernet? Then ssh will work exactly as you wish.